# How to change Sign up page design in Moodle

Tags: php, css, html, moodle

I am new to moodle and i am using 2.9. I have a separate design for Signup page (HTML5 & CSS). How to integrate this page ?

I know the process of changing the default Login page like this

In config.php of my theme

```
   'login' => array(
    'file' => 'login.php',
    'regions' => array(),
    'options' => array('langmenu'=>true),
),
```

Where my Custom login page is login.php which is placed in my layout folder. So in this way i can takeover Login page design with my new design.

But i don't see any signup array in config page for Registration. So anyone can tell me how to do this change ?

Edit - I have checked this file moodle2\login\index_form.html I can see the signup design. But my issue is that file index_form.html has Moodle core CSS if i add my CSS there it will conflict also i dont know how to load the CSS from my theme folder to index_form.html.

Can anyone guide me ?

I already checked Moodle.org forum but not able to find the process.

Thanks In Advance

Lorry

Answer (score 3):

Further to what @davosmith mentioned, you can actually use the existing auth/email plugin as a base for your plugin, So:

1. Copy auth/email and rename it to whatever you want, for example auth/foo. And rename all other instances of "email" to "foo".
2. Copy the login/signup_form.php to your plugin directory
3. in your auth/foo/auth.php file, add a function:

   ```
   function signup_form() {
       global $CFG;

       require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/auth/foo/signup_form.php');
       return new login_signup_form(null, null, 'post', '', 
       array('autocomplete'=>'on'));
   }
   ```
4. Modify the auth/foo/signup_form.php to whatever you want

Answer (score 1):

Hiii,

I'm one of the Moodler who working with Moodle.

to edit the signup page go at the following location and open the signup.php file.

```
./moodle/login/signup.php
```

in that file you can see at bottom of the page three lines.

```
...
echo $OUTPUT->header();
$mform_signup->display();
echo $OUTPUT->footer();
```

in which  $mform signup->display(); create a form yu can comment and write HTML for your sign up form.

But make sure about the Action URL and the validations.

```
$mform is the object that create form and its class file is signup_form.php.
```

Hope it helpful for you ... Good Luck ['}

Comment: Thanks for your update. I will try that. But One question in my signup page i have more css files. Which i already put in theme folder. So How can i include them in signup.php ?? Can you please guide me ?

Comment: you can include that files in header file of your theme and that header file we included already in our signup page using $OUTPUT->header(). Got it?

Comment: i didnt get you. Can you please explain. I dont have any header file in my theme folder. Sorry i am bit noob in Moodle :(

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to avoid making changes to the core code in Moodle (which should almost always be what you want), then you can create a new signup form from scratch by first creating a new authentication plugin (in auth/NAMEOFPLUGIN).

When you create the authentication plugin, you should make sure that the 'can_signup' function returns true, that the 'user_signup' function does whatever processing is needed to create the new user account and that the 'signup_form' function returns a custom [Moodle form](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Form_API) that contains the fields you want.

It is possible to further customise this form by outputting custom HTML elements (using $mform->addElement('html', 'The HTML to output'); ). I would not advise completely abandoning the Moodle form (i.e. to replace it with hand-coded custom elements), as that will not be compatible with the signup code in login/signup.php (as well as losing the validation rules that are supported by the forms library).